# How to put a delimiter before every b tag - Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I have this code:

```
print([x.text.replace('\n', '').encode('windows-1252', errors='replace') for x 
in soup.find_all(['b','p'])])
```

I would like before every `<b>` just to put some delimiter such as "**" or whatever.

Thanks

Comment: How about CSS instead of modifying the HTML? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
newstring = string.replace('<b>', '<b>**')
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Problem is I need the text output so I need to keep the <b> intact, so i can target these tags.

Comment: oh wait sorry didn't actually read your code properly that might work let me have a go

Comment: Great!*********